# Simulate scroll event on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, safari

Generally speaking, on an iPad, if we have a fixed width/height iframe element , it should scroll automatically using 2-fingers..

But because of some issue/bug in the latest IOS, we are unable to scroll the fixed dimension element..

So is there any library or any alternate by which I can wither use iframe / object element and add code which would simulate scrolling..

I can use object element, in case there is a issue with iframe unable to receive events..But I need either of these, as I have to include a child page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your looking for: http://cubiq.org/iscroll
Tried it, works fine

Comment: I did try that..works for div, but not for iframe..do u have any example for iframe where it is working ?

Comment: I have not tried with iFrame. I would try to stay off iFrames in general, there are too many drawbacks using them. But I guess you have no choice if you're doing that... hmmm, I would have a look at the tools sectino in phonegap http://www.phonegap.com/tools they list a bunch of js tools you can use (and don't need to use phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [event.initEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent). However, it's just sugestion - I'm not able to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I use plain jquery to do the scrolling:

```
function scroll(div, px){
   $(div).animate({scrollTop:$(div).scrollTop()+px}, 400);
}
```

for 200px, use as:

```
scroll('#my_iframe_id', 200);
```

Comment: Hi..Thx a lot..But is this for desktop browsers or even for mobile browsers like iPad Safari..

Comment: Also when you say 200px, that would mean fixed scrolling...I want to kind of create a natural scrolling...i.e. on the iPad, simulate what would happen when a user actually scrolls using 2-finger..

Comment: have you tried it? you can change the 200 by any other value and I'm adding 200 to the position of the element. I'm using this with many different browsers, never caused any issue..